# Is is possible to maximise the efficiency of my code using NumPy instead of built-in list?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm currently using two for loops to process data in a text file. 
The format of file is like this:

```
id1, x1 y1 z1, x2 y2 z2,.....
id2, x3 y3 z3, x4 y4 z4,.....
......
```

While I found it's inefficient when the data size is large(i.e. over 1GB)

In my code, data is stored in a 2-d list:

```
[[id1,...],
 [id2,...],
 ...]
```

```py
with open("data", "r") as f:
    lists = []
    objects = f.readlines()
    for obj in objects:
        i = obj.split(",")
        oid = [i[0]]
        for points in i[1:]:
            points = points.split(" ")
            latitude = int(points[1]) / 10000
            longitude = int(points[0]) / 1000
            coordinate = str(latitude) + " " + str(longitude)
            oid.append(coordinate)
        lists.append(oid)

w = open("output", "w")
w.writelines(",".join(i) + "\n" for i in lists)
w.close()
```

I did some processing and wrote to a new file.

I am just getting to know numpy and wondering if it is possible to speedup my code by using numpy arrays.

Thanks!

Comment: Why did 3rd `z` value `points[2]` not used (but present)?

Comment: Yes probably. What type is your data? Is it all numbers or is there some text in there?

Comment: yes, all numbers

Comment: @Kakaa, once again - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726333/is-is-possible-to-maximise-the-efficiency-of-my-code-using-numpy-instead-of-buil#comment101892925_57726333

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest that's why I have to process it

Comment: @Kakaa, you did not process  `z` value at `points[2]` - elaborate your question

Comment: You line requires two levels of delimier split.  `numpy` csv loaders only work with one delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that bad memory management slows down your script, not the native python code.

Before using numpy, I would recommend to start removing the ".readlines()" that forces your script to load all the file in memory: that should save you a lot of time on big files.

The script will then load every line one by one without storing everything in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy you can simply do that:

```py
import numpy as np

# convert your 2d-list to numpy array like this
mydata = np.array([[2,1,3],
                  [4,5,6],
                  [2,9,8]])

# I recommend you to do the processing here, not where you save the file.

#finally save it
with open('data.txt', 'w') as file:
    np.savetxt(file, mydata, delimiter = ',')
```

I think it should speed up your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach *suffers* with a great space/gaps of optimization with pure Python (even without involving `numpy`).

Use the following optimized approach:

```
with open('data.txt') as f_in, open('output.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        line = line.strip()
        id_, *items = line.split(",")
        for coords in items:
            long, lat, _ = coords.split()
            id_ += ',{} {}'.format(str(int(lat) / 1000), str(int(long) / 1000))
        f_out.write(id_ + '\n')
        id_ = ''   # clear resulting value
```

Comment: I tested on my laptop it's even 10s slower than my original code.